# AM-GM-HM Relationship

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic, means

and  are the geometric mean and the harmonic mean of any two positive (identical or nonidentical)
integers. Calculate the minimum value of their arithmetic mean in terms of  and .

HM= $\frac {GM^2}{AM}$

AM= $\frac {GM^2}{HM}$

So, AM=$\frac {x^2}{y}$

My conclusion is that minimum value of AM is $\frac{x^2}{y}$.Am I correct?

Comment: Somebody help please

Comment: mention anything if you find it doesn't help you

Comment: @PiGuy It was helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, given the AM,GM and HM there's no other way to get their relation. So that is the only possible equation to relate the Means.You are correct.